# No puedo hacer que mi programa escriba la indicacion

Tags: c#

Mi código es:

```
// Encuentre la serie alterna para 1/50
double sumatoria = 0;
Console.Write("=" + 1 + "-");
for (int i =1; i <51; i++)
{
    Console.Write("1" + "/" + i + " - " );
    sumatoria = sumatoria + (1.0 / i);
}
Console.WriteLine(" La sumatoria es " + sumatoria);
Console.WriteLine(" Presione ENTER para terminar");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Encuentre la serie alternada para 1/50

Serie alternada = 1 – 1/2 + 1/3 – 1/4 + 1/5 – 1/6 + 1/7 – 1/8 +

Sumatoria =

La salida es:

> =1-1/1 - 1/2 - 1/3 - 1/4 - 1/5 - 1/6 - 1/7 - 1/8 - 1/9 - 1/10 - 1/11 - 1/12 - 1/13 - 1/14 - 1/15 - 1/16 - 1/17 - 1/18 - 1/19 - 1/20 - 1/21 - 1/22 - 1/23 - 1/24 - 1/25 - 1/26 - 1/27 - 1/28 - 1/29 - 1/30 - 1/31 - 1/32 - 1/33 - 1/34 - 1/35 - 1/36 - 1/37 - 1/38 - 1/39 - 1/40 - 1/41 - 1/42 - 1/43 - 1/44 - 1/45 - 1/46 - 1/47 - 1/48 - 1/49 - 1/50 -  La sumatoria es 4.49920533832942
> Presione ENTER para terminar

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, publica tu código para poder trabajar con el y ayudarte mas fácilmente.

Comment: Como ya te han comentado, en el sitio se pide que el código se ponga como texto y no como imagen, de tal manera que se facilite que otros puedan copiar y pegarlo para probarlo. Por otro lado, es deseable tambien una explicación mas clara del problema. Te lanza alguna excepción? no muestra el resultado correcto?

Comment: lo que imprime es eso

Comment: =1-1/1 - 1/2 - 1/3 - 1/4 - 1/5 - 1/6 - 1/7 - 1/8 - 1/9 - 1/10 - 1/11 - 1/12 - 1/13 - 1/14 - 1/15 - 1/16 - 1/17 - 1/18 - 1/19 - 1/20 - 1/21 - 1/22 - 1/23 - 1/24 - 1/25 - 1/26 - 1/27 - 1/28 - 1/29 - 1/30 - 1/31 - 1/32 - 1/33 - 1/34 - 1/35 - 1/36 - 1/37 - 1/38 - 1/39 - 1/40 - 1/41 - 1/42 - 1/43 - 1/44 - 1/45 - 1/46 - 1/47 - 1/48 - 1/49 - 1/50 -  La sumatoria es 4.49920533832942
 Presione ENTER para terminar

Comment: Lo que has puesto en los comentarios, lo debes poner en la pregunta para que sea más claro. Por favor, edita tu pregunta :)

Comment: Y el problema cual es? la alternancia entre "+" y "-"? no me queda claro

Comment: @LuisCarlos Cual es la salida que deberías tener?

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu `for` tienes que evaluar en que poscion esta, si es par, pones '-', si es impar '+'.

Es lo que le falta a tu codigo, ya que siempre pones '-'.

```
for (int i =1; i <51; i++)
{
    //Miramos si es par
    if(i%2 == 0){
        Console.Write("1" + "/" + i + " - " );
        sumatoria = sumatoria - (1.0 / i);
    }else{
        Console.Write("1" + "/" + i + " + " );
        sumatoria = sumatoria + (1.0 / i);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta está en que hay que ir alternando los signos en la sumatoria. Lo voy explicando sobre el código:

```
// Encuentre la serie alterna para 1/50
// Inicialmente comenzamos desde 1 
double sumatoria = 1;
// Esta variable nos permitirá alternar valores 0 y 1 para
// distinguir entre - y +
int signo = 1;  

// Este array nos permitirá imprimir el signo adecuado
// en función del valor de la variable signo: un 0 para
// el signo menos y un 1 para el signo mas.
string[] strSigno = new string[] {" - ", " + "};

// Iniciamos la impresión por pantalla "=1 + "
Console.Write("=" + 1 + strSigno[signo] );

// Iteramos comenzando en 2 dado que inicialmente partíamos de 1
for (int i = 2; i <51; i++)
{
   // Cada vez que se ejecute esta línea, una vez
   // valdrá cero y la siguiente 1 y así sucesivamente,
   signo = 1 - signo;
  
   // Continuamos con la impresión de la serie, si se trata
   // del último elemento evitamos imprimir el signo.
   if (i==50)
     Console.Write("1" + "/" + i + " ");
   else
     Console.Write("1" + "/" + i + strSigno[signo] );
  
   // Y en la sumatoria multiplico el valor por el signo
   // que lo averiguo con la sentencia (signo==1 ? 1: -1) que
   // me dará 1 o -1 según valor la variable signo
   sumatoria = sumatoria + (1.0 / i) * (signo==1 ? 1: -1);
}
Console.WriteLine(" La sumatoria es " + sumatoria);
Console.WriteLine(" Presione ENTER para terminar");
Console.ReadLine();
```

El resultado del código sería:

=1 + 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/4 - 1/5 + 1/6 - 1/7 + 1/8 - 1/9 + 1/10 - 1/11 + 1/12 - 1/13 +
1/14 - 1/15 + 1/16 - 1/17 + 1/18 - 1/19 + 1/20 - 1/21 + 1/22 - 1/23 + 1/24 - 1/25 +
1/26 - 1/27 + 1/28 - 1/29 + 1/30 - 1/31 + 1/32 - 1/33 + 1/34 - 1/35 + 1/36 - 1/37 +
1/38 - 1/39 + 1/40 - 1/41 + 1/42 - 1/43 + 1/44 - 1/45 + 1/46 - 1/47 + 1/48 - 1/49 +
1/50  La sumatoria es 0.683247160575918
Presione ENTER para terminar